# Finding a Taylor expansion of $e^{-x}$ using $e^{x}$

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

I want a Taylor expansion about $x = - 4$ for the function $f(x)=e^{-x}$.

I instead find the Taylor expansion of $f(x)=e^{x}$ about $x=-4$ and then replace $x$ by$-x$ but this gives me a wrong answer.

This is what I did:

> $f(x)=e^{x}$, expanding it about $x=-4$ gives,
> $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-4}}{n !}(x+4)^{n}=e^{x}$

> Replacing $x$ by$-x$ I get
> $e^{-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-4}}{n !}(-x+4)^{n}$

.Which is incorrect. Can anyone please show me what's wrong in my approach?

Comment: If you replace $x$ by $-x$, what you get instead is the Taylor expansion of $f(x) = e^{-x}$ about $-x = -4$.

Comment: What happened when you simply took the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ and plugged $x = -4$ directly into the formula?

Comment: Start with the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ about $x=4$, not about $x=-4$. Then replace $x$ with $-x$.

Comment: @player3236 thank you. How do you know that I've got a Taylor expansion about $-x=-4$ ?

Comment: The $x$ in " expanding it about $x=-4$" is replaced by $-x$, giving $-x=-4$. Besides, the term in the expansion being raised to the $n$-th power, $(-x+4)$, is zero at $x=4$. This shows that this expansion is centered at $x=4$.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^{-x}= e^4e^{-(x+4)}=e^4 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(x+4)^n}{n!}.$$